# How do I tell what my odbc driver connection information is?

Tags: sql, r, odbc

I am using the r package RODBC. I am wanting to connect to some tables that I made for my grad school program. I know the server number. I am wondering how I tell what my driver and actual database name. The schema that I am connecting to is IS521FA1B12 so I am wondering if that is it (select * from IS521FA1B12.tablename).

This is the code that R is wanting to me to use I think.

```
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=mysqlhost;database=mydbname;trusted_connection=true')
```

Comment: Launch up the ODBC Admin utility odbcad32.exe, (note that there are 2 versions, 64 bit and 32 bit) and review the information there. You can also find the drivers information in the registry, where the ODBC utility reads from. To find the database name, go into MySQL workbench and connect to the server. You are theoretically correct about the schema.

Comment: What do you mean when you say ODBC Admin utility odbcad32.exe? I am not familiar with that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/admin/odbc-data-source-administrator